# Why some data is missing on a figure when I define the axes? My dataset is a DataArray and some values are masked

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, figure, masked-array

I would like to be able to define my axis and not lose information. Currently, I am missing the last data point in both dimensions I defined (see figure).

[image: Two panels with the same data, but the axes are different. On the left panel, the axes are not defined and thus represent the size of the data. On the right panel, the axes are defined but we are missing the last data point in each dimension.]

```
DATA = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(74,13),dims=('section','lag'))
DATA = DATA.where(DATA>.98,drop=True)

fig,(ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,2))

ax0.pcolor(DATA)
ax0.set(title='Axes not defined')

ax1.pcolor(DATA.lag, DATA.section, DATA)
ax1.set(title='Axes defined')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You could make your post clearer by providing some easily-reproducible test data. And also add `import`s.  Note that [`ax.pcolor(X, Y, C)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html) considers `X` and `Y` the corners of the color grid.  So, if you have `10` colors in the x direction, you need `11` corner positions. This might need a manual calculation of an extra corner point.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this: Since my data is a DataArray, I could redefine the coordinates and plot it with xarray:

```
DATA.assign_coords(section=a,lag=b)
DATA.plot.pcolor()
```